# Second component is not read in app.components.ts file (Angular 2)

Tags: html, angular, angular-components

I want to create components for every html element. The problem that i am facing is that it is not able to read the second component. Only the dropdown list is displayed.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `<dropdown-fs></dropdown-fs>`,
  directives: [DropdownComponent]
 })

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
template: `<table-fs></table-fs>`,
directives: [TableComponent]
})
```

Comment: They have the same selector? Might want to change that.

Comment: @rrd I tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: Please show your module file and the html when you are using this components